# click row item but return all the rows in cursor used to build the list

Tags: android

I use `SimpleCursorAdapter` build a list. And I want to start another activity when I click one of the rows. code as following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_list);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.user_list);
    db.open();
    fillData();
     .......
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor selectedItem = (Cursor) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Log.d("#####", selectedItem.getCount() +"");
            // return total number of the cursor using to build the list.
            selectedItem.moveToFirst();
            .......               
        }
    });
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = db.fetchAllSenders();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[] {PeerContract.KEY_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.user_list_row_name};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.user_list_row, c, from, to, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But int the LogCat `Log.d("#####", selectedItem.getCount() +"");` always return the total number of rows in cursor used to build the list. For example, there are 4 rows in the list, after I click one row in the list, the LogCat will display `#####:4`. But it supposes to be `1` when I click just one item. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is coming 4 because there is only one cursor reference with the adapter. the method getAdapter().getItem(position) will return you the same cursor object but it will move the cursor to the position for which you requested getItem().

So whenever you call getItem(position), it will not give you a new cursor object, it will give you the same cursor object, moving it to the current position